# Problems remoting in Win Server 2019 through OpenVPN

Tags: routing, windows-server-2019

Today I have set up a VPN using a Raspberry-pi and OpenVPN. The VPN is now connected from both my Windows 10 laptop and my Android mobile phone, not without pain.

I need to remote into my home server but I am stumbling into what seems to be a **routing** problem.

- My target network is a private IPv4 network 192.168.144.0/24

  - I need to access 192.168.144.11 (Windows Server 2019)
  - HP iLO firmware address is 192.168.144.28, keep this in mind
  - Raspy is 192.168.144.13
  - Main gateway is 192.168.144.1
- I have set up routing tables at the gateway

  - 172.16.0.0/16 routed via raspberry
  - 192.168.0.0/24 routed via raspberry who owns a permanent VPN link to another site. This is out of the scope of the question

With my laptop, I present myself as 172.16.46.10 and the raspberry routes my traffic to its `eth0` interface.

I could verify that I can access the `https` interface for the iLO server. For those who don't know, a lot of HP (micro) servers come with a firmware agent providing a lot of features (including remote console and ability to push the power button) from a web interface.

Since **I can access** iLO and power the microserver on, I have determined that most of my routing is correct.

However, I still can't remote using rdp.

I have tried the following to investigate:

- RDP fails to connect
- `ping 191.168.144.11` from remote laptop, no response
- `tracert` the same address hits only the 172.16.46.1 VPN gateway, without going further
- `ping 172.16.46.10` from the Windows Server machine works. I can ping back my laptop
- `ping 192.168.144.28`, which is iLO, works
- `tracert` the above hits the server with 2 hops
- `http://192.168.144.1` loads an HTML forbidden page, **which is correct** because I am trying to hit the home router with a foreign address
- And of course `https://192.168.144.28` works like a charm. I can login into the server via serial console and issue commands here (see #4)
- SMBing `\\192.168.144.11` does not work from remote laptop

Judging from the various tests, this looks like to me a like a pure routing or firewalling problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was writing the question, I finally found the answer myself.

I needed to add a static route to Windows Server, don't ask me why

```
route add -p 172.16.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.144.13
```

Once the route was `OK` I could do everything with the server. I'll try to understand it better later